# Not getting expected output for Left join on multiple variable in R

Tags: r, merge, sqldf

Please see below code of `R`, I want to do left join on multiple variable but not getting expected output... can anyone help me to find out what's wrong with below code...

```r
x <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
                b = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
                c = c(12, 34, 56, 776, 88, 99, 44, 90, 88, 55),
                d = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "BB", "AA", "BB"),
                e = c("as", "saa", "sxs", "xxz", "dcd", "cc", "ccd", "xx", "cdc", "hghg"),
                f = c(12, 23, 455, 44, 34, 66, 44, 55, 44, 11))

y <- data.frame(g = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
                h = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"),
                i = c(12, 88, 99, 88, 55, 44, 66) ,
                j = c("AA", "EE", "FF", "AA", "BB", "GG", "ii"),
                k = c("12", "34", "df", "56", "4", "fdd", "ff"))

join_df <- "select
            x.* , y.i, y.k*
            from x
            left join y
            on x.a = y.g AND x.b = y.h AND x.d = y.j"

x[order(x$a, x$b, x$d), ]
y[order(y$g, y$h, y$j), ]
    
mxy <- sqldf(join_df)
mxy
```

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: You can use `left_join` from `dplyr`. BTW can you show the expected output

Comment: You have an extra `*` after `y.k`, it works fine for me after removing it.

Comment: Thanks for help... extra * creating problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `left_join` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x, y, by = c(a="g", b="h", d="j"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `join` query like the following

```
join_df <- "select
    x.* , y.i, y.k
    from x left outer join y
    on x.a = y.g AND x.b = y.h AND x.d = y.j"

library(sqldf)
sqldf(join_df)
#    a b   c  d    e   f  i    k
#1   1 a  12 AA   as  12 12   12
#2   2 b  34 BB  saa  23 NA <NA>
#3   3 c  56 CC  sxs 455 NA <NA>
#4   4 d 776 DD  xxz  44 NA <NA>
#5   5 e  88 EE  dcd  34 NA <NA>
#6   6 f  99 FF   cc  66 NA <NA>
#7   7 g  44 GG  ccd  44 NA <NA>
#8   8 h  90 BB   xx  55 NA <NA>
#9   9 i  88 AA  cdc  44 NA <NA>
#10 10 j  55 BB hghg  11 NA <NA>
```

With `base R` we can get same results with

```
merge(x, y, by.x=c('a', 'b', 'd'), by.y=c('g', 'h', 'j'), all.x=TRUE)
```

The following benchmark test shows the comparison of performance with different `join` methods, `dplyr join` being the fastest.

```
library('microbenchmark')
microbenchmark(sqldf_join=sqldf(join_df), 
               merge=merge(x, y, by.x=c('a', 'b', 'd'), by.y=c('g', 'h', 'j'), all.x=TRUE), 
               dplyr_join=left_join(x, y, by = c("a"="g", "b"="h", "d"="j")), times=100)

#Unit: microseconds
#       expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
# sqldf_join 14068.131 14593.290 15520.0908 15072.2635 16411.678 19768.767   100   c
#      merge  1590.021  1669.992  1770.4099  1724.3045  1772.201  3834.781   100  b 
# dplyr_join   506.343   561.298   608.4422   607.0565   646.187   837.349   100 a
```